# Depth of $M$ on $I$ well defined without homological arguments

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring, $I \trianglelefteq R$ a ideal
and $M$ a Noetherian $R$-module. Assume $IM \neq M$.

We call a sequence
$x_1,x_2,..., x_n \in R$ with $x_i \in I$ regular if
for every  $1 \le i < n$ the element $x_i $ is not a zerodivisor
of module $M/(x_1,...,x_i)M$.

Now starting with arbitrary regular sequence $x_1,x_2,..., x_k$
using Noether property one can show that every such sequence can be extended
to a maximal regular sequence $x_1,x_2,..., x_k, ..., x_N$ which
cannot be extended properly. That means that there exist no
$x_{N+1} \in R$ which is not a zero divisor on $M/(x_1,...,x_N)M$.

In order to define depth of $M$ on $I$ we have to assume that
every maximal regular sequence have same length $N$. That means
that is we have two maximal regular sequences $x_1,..., x_N$
and $y_1,...,y_S$ which are maximal in sense above then $N=S$.

Question: I'm looking for a **non homological** proof of the
claim that all maximal regular sequences have the same lenght.

Our business to show that if $x_1,..., x_N$
and $y_1,...,y_S$ which are maximal regular sequences then $N=S$. I found a lot of proofs using homological methods by exploying properties of $Ext$'s. The concern of my question is if it is also possible to proof the claim above without mathods from homological algebra.

Comment: I seem to remember that Sharp's *Steps in Commutative Algebra* proves this without any homological algebra.

Comment: Kaplansky did this, too.